# Error in optim(par = params, fn = Log_vrais, data = BTdata, id = id) : 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Tags: r, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

This is my first time using the optim function in R, and I am having some trouble figuring out what I am doing wrong. I have multiple observations by subject. My objective is to fit joint model with gamma prior(alpha,alpha). The data below is not my real data but an example I give with the code.

I want to find the maximum for

[image]

```
library(JM)
data(aids, package = "JM")
data(pbc2.id, package = "JM")
aids[aids$patient %in% c(1,2), c("patient", "CD4", "obstime")]
pbc2.id$patient=pbc2.id$id
BTdata <- aids

BTdata$offset_reg=log(BTdata$Time)
pbc2.id$status<- ifelse(pbc2.id$status %in% c("alive"), '0', ifelse(pbc2.id$status%in% 
c("dead"), '1', '2')) 
table(pbc2.id$status)
lmeFit.int <- lme(CD4 ~drug+gender+AZT+offset_reg, random = ~ 1 | patient,
                  data = BTdata,method = c('ML'))
 pbc2.id$status2 <- as.numeric(pbc2.id$status != "alive")

 coxFit <- coxph(Surv(years, status2) ~ drug + age + sex,
              data = pbc2.id)


 # Valeurs initiaux

 parm_1=fixef(lmeFit.int)    
 parm_2=coef(coxFit)  #  
 parm_1=c(parm_1)
 parm_2=c(parm_2)
 alpha=2 # we suppose we have  gamma prior with both parameters equal to 2
 id=unique(BTdata$patient)
 params=list(parm_1,parm_2)

 Log_vrais<- function(params) {
 id=BTdata$patient[i]  
 BTdata_id=subset(BTdata,patient==id)#
 BTdata_id$status<- ifelse(pbc2.id$status %in% c("alive"), '0', 
 ifelse(pbc2.id$status%in% c("dead"), '1', '2'))  

 delta=pbc2.id[,3]     #$status2
 delta=as.numeric(delta)
 y_CD4=BTdata_id[,4]   #$CD4
 t_i=BTdata_id[,13] #
 beta_0=rep(1,length(BTdata_id[,13]))
 G_T<-cbind(beta_0,BTdata_id[,c(6,7,9,13)])
 G_T=data.matrix(G_T)
 
 W_T<-(pbc2.id[,c(4:6)])
 W_T=data.matrix(W_T)
 beta=as.matrix(params[[1]],nrow=length(params[[1]]))
 beta_prime=as.matrix(params[[2]],nrow=length(params[[2]]))
 lambda=exp(G_T %*% beta)
 k_i=exp(W_T%*%beta_prime)
 class(y_CD4)
 comp1=log(gamma(delta +y_CD4+alpha)) -log(gamma(delta+1))-log(gamma(y_CD4 + 1))- 
 log(gamma(alpha))
 comp2=alpha*log(alpha+y_CD4%*%log(lambda)+delta%*%log(k_i))
 comp3=-(alpha+ y_CD4+delta)%*%log(lambda+k_i %*% c(t(t_i))+alpha)
 loglike = sum(comp1+comp2+comp3)
 return(-loglike) 
 }
 for (i in id ){ 
 fit1 <- optim(par=params,fn=Log_vrais, data=BTdata, id=id) 
 }
```